# SQLITE DATABASE RESETS in ANDROID on application opening the second time,once the data is inserted

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I m implementing sqlite db(database) for my android application.When i open my app i insert data into the database and the application exits.When i open the app second time and try to retrieve data i just inserted the app crashes after i click on button meant for retrieving data from database.Is the database reset everytime i open my app or their is some problem with the way i implemented database.
this is my code:

//For creating table:

private static String SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME = "PERSONS_TABLE";

private SQLiteDatabase sampleDB;

```
private void createTable()
{
   sampleDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                " (COUNT INT(3),PERSON_NAME VARCHAR); ");   
}
```

//Inserting

```
private void insertData()
{
    sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME + " Values ('"+c+"','"+pass+"');");
}
```

//    For retrieving just the 1st column

```
 public int cdata()
{
    cursor = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT FROM " +
            SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME, null);
     if (cursor != null)
     {
          cursor.moveToFirst();


              c=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("COUNT"));

         cursor.close();

     }
    return c;
}
```

I m then using this c to set my textview to value in database using a button so that on button click ,i get to know whether their is any data in database w.r.t that column,but the second time i open the app.
So this time it crashes.

Code for store voice recognized word in database after user clicks on a button named 'yes'
//using this to store voice recognized word

@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {

```
       if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        // Populate the wordsList with the String values the recognition engine thought it heard
        ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

        pass = matches.get(0);
```

Button yes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

```
yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view)
        {  
            try
            {
                c=1;
                sampleDB = openOrCreateDatabase("NAME", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                createTable();
                insertData();
                seeData();

            }
            catch (SQLiteException se)
            {
                Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
            }
            finally
            {

                if (sampleDB != null)
                    sampleDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME);
                sampleDB.close();
            }
        }} );






          private void seeData()
          {
    TextView txts=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);


    cursor = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT,PERSON_NAME FROM " +
            SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME, null);

    if (cursor != null)
    {
         cursor.moveToFirst();


             String personName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PERSON_NAME"));
             c=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("COUNT"));
                //String country = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("COUNTRY"));
                //int age = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("AGE"));
             txts.setText(personName);
             if ( pass.equals(personName))
             {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device is unlocked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();

             }
             else
             {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "WRONG PASSWORD", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }

        cursor.close();
    }

  }
```

Comment: add your logcat output, and also the code that initializes sampleDB

Comment: sampleDB is initialized using SQliteOpenhelper as i have mentioned ...
adding logcat now wait...

Comment: It would still be beneficial to see what you are doing with the database. As in, when/where you are opening the database, when where you are calling the method for table creation etc etc.

Comment: i added the code for insertion and creation of table...

Comment: change seedata() to cdata()

Comment: actually i hv both the functions cdata()(for count) and seedata(for person name)

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
public int cdata()
{
    cursor = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " +
            SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME, null);
     if (cursor != null)
     {
         cursor.moveToFirst();
         c=cursor.getInt(0);
         cursor.close();
     }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: actually i wanted to know whether my database is reseting which it should nt after opening the app the 2nd time ..

Comment: if you want to know if your data has been stored properly just use [SQLitebrowser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/) to view your database data.

Comment: The database not resetting, whatever that means. getInt(0) returns the first column in the projection, which in this case is COUNT(*). If you really have to do it your way, change the SQL to "SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT...".